# Правильный ли подход к модели?

Tags: model, php, mvc

Вообщем есть цели построить конструкцию простенькой модели, так сказать для общего развития, опираться на принципы реализации в известных фреймворках я не стал, решил придумать что-то своё. Но возник вопрос, правильный ли это подход или нет.

Базовая модель

```
abstract class Model {

    protected $db;
    protected $data = array();
    protected $type;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Registry::get('db');
    }

    public function select($data, $type) {

        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE $data[0]", $data[1]);

        switch($type):

        case 'object':
        $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        break;

        case 'assoc':
        $result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        break;

        endswitch;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Дочерняя модель

```
class Model_User extends Model {

protected $table;
protected $data;

    public function __construct($table) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function getObjUser($data) {
        return parent::select($data, $type = 'object');
    }

}
```

Использование в контроллере

```
$model = new Model_User('users');
$data = array('id = :id', array('id' => 1));
$obj = $model->getObjUser($data);
echo $obj->login;
```

Опираюсь на простоту и понятность, для себя. Поэтому строго не ругайте. Желательно услышать советы, или увидеть чьи-то варианты.

Спасибо за внимание..

Comment: нет не правильный. модель это не то что работает с базой данных, это то что работает с данными, поэтому  реализация select в базовом классе модели неуместна.

Comment: @eicto то есть, сами запросы нужно писать в классе бд, и передавать из модели.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая напрямую на вопрос не существует понятия правильно или не правильно забудьте эти два понятия. Есть инструменты, которые выполняют свою функцию и применимы в вашей ситуации, а есть те, которые не выполняют либо не применимы, выбор тех или иных - исключительно ваш выбор.

То, что не является ответом:
Не соглашусь с коллегой в комментарии. По википедии:

> Модель (Model) предоставляет данные и реагирует на команды
>   контроллера, изменяя свое состояние.

Т.е. допустимо в модели писать запросы в БД, однако тут же соглашусь с коллегой во второй части тезиса: реализация их в базовом классе - неуместна, но по причине того, что для каждой модели эти запросы будут разными.

Теоретически: можно реализовать общий запрос в базовом классе, но необходимо, чтобы на вход (в вашем случае) приходило подготовленное PDOStatement, а так же потребуются хитрые манипуляции с биндами значений. Если вам интересен такой подход - я бы рекомендовал его реализовать, хотя бы для практики и выявления недостатков.